# Cycles - losing renders layers

Tags: rendering

I am trying to composite two render layers, but compositor is acting a little odd. I unchecked backdrop for a moment and the image completely disappeared from compositor as well as the image editor.

I have also noticed that I had to fiddle with the zoom level for the renders to show up, I'd have to reset zoom levels and still use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to zoom.

I am using Blender 2.74. Rendering on Phenom(tm)II X4 965 CPU. Any help? Can not afford to rerender.. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Can you post a blend file that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Happens with multiple files.

Comment: Are your 2 render layers saved out to external files, or are they just in blender in the temporary frame buffer? You should save them out to file if you want to avoid re-rendering. Then we can fix the compositing issue after that.

Comment: That's what I usually do, just clicked around a minute right before saving in the compositor bc I couldn't see the renders and for a minute it seemed like if I unchecked backdrop and checked it again might have fixed it. But instead in composting view it only deleted it from image editor slot, after which I just lost it completely.

Comment: If you have to render it again, render it out to a multilayer exr file without the compositor. Then you can composite from the exr file and make sure you don't lose your render again.

Comment: This sounds great, accept I am a little unclear on what you mean by "without the compositor, does that mean I can or should somehow exclude the compositor? I am not even sure of what that might mean. Correct me if I am wrong but I think you are just suggestions to save a file AFTER re-rendering. That gets us back to my issue of not wanting to take one more day to render. But thanks for your input. Is there a temp file for the renders or anything like for Maya where if u save it in buffer it's temporarily stored on your computer? bc if there is I can not find it.